# How to work with shift and unshift function in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript.

How to work with `shift` and `unshift` function in VBScript ?

Comment: Can you show a code sample that clarifies your question?

Comment: I think is ia very good question, i like the old programming concepts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`shift`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9e7b4w20) and [`unshift`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ezk94dwt) are JavaScript methods. They're not available in VBScript. If you need the functionality they provide, you basically have 2 options:

- Use the .Net class [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx):

  ```
  Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
  a.Add "a"
  a.Add "b"
  a.Add "c"

  WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a.ToArray, ",") & "]"

  'insert at beginning of array
  a.Insert 0, "z"

  WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a.ToArray, ",") & "]"

  'remove from beginning of array
  v = a(0)
  a.RemoveAt 0

  WScript.Echo v
  WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a.ToArray, ",") & "]"
  ```
- Emulate the functionality with a wrapper around standard VBScript arrays. I implemented such a wrapper ([`CArray`](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/carray.shtml)) some time ago:

  ```
  Set a = New CArray
  a.Items = Array("a", "b", "c")

  WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a.ToArray, ",") & "]"

  'insert at beginning of array
  a.InsertFirst "z"

  WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a.ToArray, ",") & "]"

  'remove from beginning of array
  v = a.RemoveFirst

  WScript.Echo v
  WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a.ToArray, ",") & "]"
  ```